# Media queries plus javascript window resize different width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I'm using some javascript to detect width changes, as long as media queries. I need both as I need to move the html around. Both work, except the time at which they happen is not the same, I a guessing the scrollbar is included in one of them, but it would be foolish to assume a 15px scrollbar, as its width is not the same across browsers. Is there a better approach?

My media query activates like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 767px)" />
```

And using :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

While my JS looks like this :

```
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

var pause = 100;
$(window).resize(function() {
    delay(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
          if ( width >= 768 ) {
            if (window.myDevice != 'desktop' || window.myDevice === undefined) {
                window.myDevice = 'desktop';
                $('#head').prepend($('#branding'));
            }
        } else if ( width <= 767 ) {
            if (window.myDevice != 'mobile' || window.myDevice === undefined) {
                window.myDevice = 'mobile';
                $('#content').prepend($('#branding'));
            }
        }
    }, pause );
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Scroll bars _are_ the same across browsers, they're just different across operating systems. And even then, they tend to be somewhat the same as far as width. Even if the visual width doesn't seem that wide, the physical width is.

Comment: Is it always delayed, or just the first window resize? My guess is the delay is the length of time it takes for the browser to download the stylesheet file.

Comment: Aparently you're using in your media queries the term "device-width" so it's pretty different from the "width" on Jquery.

Comment: That's found in the viewport, not the media query.

Comment: This seemed to help : http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript

Comment: Good work, put it in as an answer and accept for future generations

Comment: @SetSailMedia that's why i say apparently, it's the most possible if he defines this meta

Answer (score 0):

Using the script found at http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript, I've resolved the issue.

Added the function

```
function viewport() {
    var e = window, a = 'inner';
    if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
        a = 'client';
        e = document.documentElement || document.body;
    }
    return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };
}
```

and then referenced the width using `viewport().width` inside my `(window).resize()` like so:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    delay(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
          if ( width >= 768 ) {
            if (window.myDevice != 'desktop' || window.myDevice === undefined) {
                window.myDevice = 'desktop';
                $('#head').prepend($('#branding'));
            }
        } else if ( width <= 767 ) {
            if (window.myDevice != 'mobile' || window.myDevice === undefined) {
                window.myDevice = 'mobile';
                $('#content').prepend($('#branding'));
            }
        }
    }, pause );
});
```